# How many Pantone colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, pantone, color-spaces, print-production

I have an illustrator file (it's a packaging design going to be printed) which I didn't design it myself.

I see so many Pantone colors in the swatches panel; the person who designed it used many Pantone colors and had no idea about printing.

The printer asked me to have only one Pantone color and the rest of the colors in the artwork should be CMYK.

**How can I identify the Pantone colors and change them into CMYK?**

Comment: Can you please address where this question being asked before?Thanks

Comment: Seems to be an odd request to make only *one* of the colors Pantone. Honestly, this is  just something the printer's prepress department should be handling for you.

Comment: @nita Did you fix your issue?

Comment: @go-me not really.. the only thing I thought I might be able to do was to select the entire artwork and edit colors convert to CMYK, then select the select the part that need to be pantone(important part of the package) and add a pantone color to it : /  I do not know if this make sense?!

Comment: Makes sense. You know, in your swatches panel, you can go in option panel in the top corner & choose "select all unused", & then "delete swatch". With the swatches left, double click the ones you don't need, & on the window that will open, select "process" on the color type menu for the pantone you want in CMYK. Then simply verify the elements that should be Pantone if they really are. To see what is in pantone, you can select one element in that pantone, and go in the menu "select" and choose "select same fill", then do the same with "select same stroke." I'll expand if question get reopened!